# Get bounding rect from path2D or context2D

Tags: javascript, matrix, canvas, path, 2d

I want to calculate the bounding rect of a shape after I scale or rotate it.

First of all, I want to get the width and height.

[image]

```js
const ctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')
let rotation = 45
let p1 = new Path2D()

p1.rect(0, 0, 75, 75)

let p2 = new Path2D()
p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().translate(80, 10).scale(1, 1.2).rotate(45))


ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
ctx.fill(p2)

//how get bounding rect from p2 or ctx { width , height ,...}
```

Comment: Would the original shape always be a square? Or are there irregular shapes as well? This would make the thing hugely more difficult

Comment: The shape can be a circle or a path.

Answer (score 3):

There is (currently) no built-in way to do so. `Path2D` objects are opaque, we can't read anything from it.
Some simple shapes would be trivial to implement, but once you start handling the full potential of the `Path2D` interface, with things like `ellipse`, `roundRect()`, `new Path2D("[the whole SVG syntax]")`, or, `path.addPath(path2, matrix)`, it becomes a lot more complicated.

In [this repo](https://github.com/Kaiido/path2D-inspection/), I did start prototyping what could be added to the `Path2D` interface to unleash its full potential, and stop it from being just an opaque object, and of course, one of the added method is `getBBox()`.

So while it's probably not 100% bug free, and while it's definitely not optimized for performances, this might suite your needs just well:

```js
const ctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')
let rotation = 45
let p1 = new Path2D()

p1.rect(0, 0, 75, 75)

let p2 = new Path2D()
p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().translate(80, 10).scale(1, 1.2).rotate(45))

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
ctx.fill(p2)

const bbox = p2.getBBox(); // a DOMRect
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.strokeRect(bbox.left, bbox.top, bbox.width, bbox.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/path2D-inspection@master/build/path2D-inspection.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I hope to be able starting the work for "speccing" all this, and gain implementers interest during next year, though I'm pretty confident for this latter since that's a very common request (which dates from when `Path2D` was first drafted), but the specs work might take a long time.

Comment: When I enter this script, the whole scene disappears.

Comment: oO Could you share a link to a public RPL, like jsfiddle where this happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, the project I am working on is extensive and personal.
But in total, it consists of several rects, circles, and paths.

Comment: @MeysamGhorbani I understand, but there's something in there that my script didn't expect and breaks it. That would be of great help for me to know what it is. Could you at least tell me what your dev-console says?

Answer (score 1):

After several days of trying to make a system similar to path2D, after scale, rotate, translate on the path, I can still calculate it and get the Bound value.

If you need, I will leave the code for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This script works perfectly. But I think it does high processing!

```js
const ctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')
ctx.canvas.width = innerWidth, ctx.canvas.height = innerHeight

let p1 = new Path2D()

p1.rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
let p2 = new Path2D()

p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().rotate(10).translate(80, 10))

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'

ctx.fill(p2)

p1 = new Path2D()

p1.arc(0, 0, 40, 0,100)
p2 = new Path2D()

p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().rotate(10).translate(80, 40))

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'

ctx.fill(p2)

const bbox = getBoundingBox(ctx, 0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

ctx.strokeStyle = "green";

ctx.strokeRect(bbox.left, bbox.top, bbox.width, bbox.height);


function getBoundingBox(ctx, left, top, width, height) {
var ret = {}, data = ctx.getImageData(left, top, width, height).data, first = false, last = false, right = false, left = false, r = height, w = 0, c = 0, d = 0;

// 1. get bottom
while (!last && r) {
    r--;
    for (c = 0; c < width; c++) {
        if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
            last = r + 1;
            ret.bottom = r + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// 2. get top
r = 0;
var checks = [];
while (!first && r < last) {
    for (c = 0; c < width; c++) {
        if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
            first = r - 1;
            ret.top = r - 1;
            ret.height = last - first - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    r++;
}

// 3. get right
c = width;
while (!right && c) {
    c--;
    for (r = 0; r < height; r++) {
        if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
            right = c + 1;
            ret.right = c + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// 4. get left
c = 0;
while (!left && c < right) {
    for (r = 0; r < height; r++)
        if (data[r * width * 4 + c * 4 + 3]) {
            left = c;
            ret.left = c;
            ret.width = right - left - 1;
            break;
        }
    c++;
    if (left) return ret;
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really gives you the bbox of the Path2D object, but of what has been painted to the context. You could refactor it so that it paints only the Path2D on another canvas, but that would anyway not work for cases where the Path2D gets outside of the canvas buffer (e.g `rect(-50, -50, 50, 50)`. Finally, indeed, it's as high cunsumptive as it can be.

Comment: Do you know a library that is separate from canvasAPI and performs scale, rotate, translate,... operations separately on the path?

Comment: This isn't really the place to make library recommendations, moreover since it doesn't seem directly related to this answer or this question. But no, I don't know any that does handle all of the Path2D API. Plus, it's quite unclear what you'd expect that library to work on exactly.